# Looping over values in an object array - nodeJS

Tags: node.js

I'm having trouble looping over all objects in my object array. I can loop over the first object but it does not move onto the next one in my for loop.

```
var results = [
 { company: 'eureka_jp', companyurl: 'hackerone.com/eureka_jp' },
 { company: 'evernote', companyurl: 'hackerone.com/evernote' },
 { company: 'exodus', companyurl: 'hackerone.com/exodus' },
],
```

This is my code that initialises the loop. The main aim of this code is to loop over each company url value and perform a web scrape identified by the page.screenshot function.

The console.log(urlLoop) returns only the first value of the companyurl property of the object.

```
  for (const value of Object.values(results)) {
  
  let urlLoop = `${value.companyurl}` 



  for (let i = 0; i < urlLoop.length; i++) {
  const browser = await puppeteer.launch({ headless: false })
  const page = await browser.newPage()
  await page.goto("https://" + urlLoop)
  await new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, 10000));
  await page.screenshot({                     

    path: "./screenshot.png",                  
 
    fullPage: true                              
 
  }) 

  console.log ("New Page");

  }
```

Comment: urlLoop is a string, you are looping over each character of the string? `console.log() = returns` is a syntax error

Comment: How would I access each object property value "companyurl" and then loop over that running my function inside?

Comment: loop directly over the array `results` and access the property `companyurl`. You don't need nested loops.

Comment: could i have some guidance on how to achieve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

***for (const value of Object.values(results))*** this line gets an array containing values of the result objects. So you're looping through the for of loop.

Again you're looping through for loop (the nested one with urlLoop length) which causes the problem.

I think this is what you're trying to do.

```
for (const value of Object.values(results)) {
  
  let urlLoop = `${value.companyurl}` 

  // remove the for loop
  
  const browser = await puppeteer.launch({ headless: false })
  const page = await browser.newPage()
  await page.goto("https://" + urlLoop)
  await new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, 10000));
  await page.screenshot({                     

    path: "./screenshot.png",                  
 
    fullPage: true                              
 
  }) 
  console.log ("New Page");
}
```